# tensor board output is not shown when I am trying to run the jupyter notebook on VSC

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I am trying to run this code on my system (Windows,VSC, Python 3.8):

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs

I can see a message saying that tensorboard is launching but nothing show:

[image]

What is the problem and how I can fix it?

## Edit1

I updated my system and tried again but still the same:

1- Jupyter is the latest version:
[image]

2- Tensorflow and tensorboard are both 2.4.1

3- still not getting the output from the tensorboard. I run the cell several times to make sure that bugs in windows don't appear here.

Comment: I can't reproduce your question and have you configured the environment correctly. View [jupyter_tensorboard](https://github.com/lspvic/jupyter_tensorboard). Also you can try it in [JupytLab](https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/jupyterlab-jupyterlab-demo-5gdmvj9i/lab) and see if the question goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added support for viewing TensorBoard inline in VS Code Jupyter notebooks in the December release of the Jupyter extension for VS Code.

You'll need to ensure that you upgrade to the latest version (2.4.1) of the TensorBoard package, and the December version of the Jupyter extension for VS Code. After that you should be good to go.

Do note that there is a known problem with TensorBoard on Windows where launching TensorBoard inline in a Jupyter notebook will time out on the first try. Simply rerunning the cell should cause the TensorBoard UI to show up inline. This has been reported and fixed in TensorBoard but has not been released in a package update yet: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/4300

If TensorBoard still doesn't show up in Jupyter notebooks in VS Code after trying the above, please feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues. We're more than happy to assist.

Comment: Not working :( please see my edit in the original question.

Comment: Sorry about that. If you run `%tensorboard --logdir logs --port 6007`, do you get a different result? Otherwise, would you mind filing a GitHub issue on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues and including the contents of the developer tools console? You can find it by running Ctrl+Shift+P to open the command palette, then type in 'Toggle Developer Tools', and select the contents of the 'Console' tab. Thanks and apologies!